# C++ core dump in Linux when using string as template type

Tags: c++, linux

This simple piece of code causes a core dump. I'm using gcc 4.8.2 in Linux.

```
template <class T>
class X
{
    T c;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    X<string> *x = new X<string>[7];
    delete x;
    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any help, I'm really confused with this. It doesn't cause a core dump when I use int instead of string.

Comment: If you use `new[]`, then you need to use `delete[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You called `new []` so you need to call `delete []`:

```
delete [] x;
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from a lot of frustration. :)